# Empty immutable collections as defaultValue in @RequestParam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Its pretty annoying that Spring don't accept non-constant values in `defaultValue` of `@RequestParam`. I would like to return an empty immutable collection for collections. Is there any beautiful workaround?

Comment: That's not Spring. That's Java annotations in general.

Comment: yes, but actually I could hook into Spring RequestArgumentResolver, check for "" and return an empty collection.

Comment: I think Collections.EMPTY_LIST is a constant collection you could use for this purpose.

Comment: `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` is a static method

Comment: And if you define your own ArgumentResolver, how do you cover the scenario where there is an actual collection (non-empty or non-null values) being passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start from something like this:
in your config file for the `DispatcherServlet` you need to register your own `ArgumentResolver` as you mentioned:

```
<annotation-driven>
        <argument-resolvers>
            <beans:bean class="com.foo.bar.CustomListWebArgumentResolver" />
        </argument-resolvers>
    </annotation-driven>
```

As I mentioned in my comment, I couldn't see initially a way of dealing with the opposite (normal) way of dealing with a parameter. The solution below doesn't look too pretty in my opinion, but I believe it might work:

```
public class CustomListWebArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Autowired
private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter;

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
    ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest = (ServletWebRequest) webRequest;
    HttpServletRequest request = servletWebRequest.getRequest();

    String value = request.getParameter(parameter.getParameterName());
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver defaultResolver = null;
    for (Iterator iterator = requestMappingHandlerAdapter.getArgumentResolvers().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        HandlerMethodArgumentResolver type = (HandlerMethodArgumentResolver) iterator.next();
        if (type instanceof RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver) {
            defaultResolver = (RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver) type;
        }
    }

    if (defaultResolver != null) {
        return defaultResolver.resolveArgument(parameter, mavContainer, servletWebRequest, binderFactory);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    return List.class.equals(parameter.getParameterType());
}
}
```

Basically, in your custom resolver you get a hold of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which has a reference to all of the default argument resolvers defined by Spring. The one you are looking for is `RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`. Once you get a hold of it, in case the value of the parameter is not null and not empty, you pass the job to the default argument resolver.

Above, in `supportsParameter` method I assumed a generic List is being handled as a `RequestParam`:

```
public String home(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "") List myList, ...) {
...
}
```

Also, I think you would need a custom configuration to make your custom resolver be considered before the default resolvers:

```
@Configuration
public class MyCustomWebConfiguration {
    private @Inject RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void prioritizeCustomArgumentMethodHandlers () {
      List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList(adapter.getArgumentResolvers ());
      List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> customResolvers = adapter.getCustomArgumentResolvers ();

      argumentResolvers.removeAll(customResolvers);
      argumentResolvers.addAll(0, customResolvers);
      adapter.setArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }
}
```